# C++ - calling to constructor on exist object

Tags: c++

I saw some code that reconsruct Object on c++.
from GeeksForGeeks :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class String
{
    char *p;
    int len;
public:
    String(const char *a);
};

String::String(const char *a)
{
    int length = strlen(a);
    p = new char[length +1];
    strcpy(p, a);
    cout << "Constructor Called " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    String s1("Geeks");  // line 1
    const char *name = "forGeeks";
    s1 = name; // line 3
    return 0;
}
```

Now, after line 3 s1 is a different object?
I always thought that after you construct object, you can't dereference it.

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to just destroy it and recycle the memory for a new object? "Dereferencing" is for pointers. See also: [Copy Constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

Comment: `s1 = String(name);` is not dereferencing. It's the replacement of the old value of `s1` `("Geeks")` with the new one `String(name)`.

Comment: I can't understand this code! Where is `operator=`?

Comment: @AhmadWabbi an explicit copy assignment, then `const char*` is explicit converted to a `String`, the `operator=(const String&)` or `operator=(String&&)` (from C++11) will be called

Answer (score 4):

What you see is an [assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment).

A copy assignment operator is automatically generated in your class, since you don't define one yourself. From the page I linked to:

> If no user-defined copy assignment operators are provided for a class
>   type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare one
>   as an inline public member of the class.

Comment: link to the rule of three/five somehow, or this will add to the confusion for people new to cpp.

Comment: I am not sure if design rules are relevant to teach at this level. I agree that it is an important rule though.

Comment: Well the next person who doesn't know will have a custom destructor and will wonder, why this does not work for him/her.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down.

```
s1 = name;
```

First, the compiler will construct a new `String` object using the constructor `String(char const*)`. Then it uses the copy assignment operator to update `s1` with this newly created object.

Since you did not define this operator, it simply does a copy of the class members, i.e. `p` and `len`: that's the default implementation the compiler generates for you. The old object is not cleaned up before so you are leaking memory... You should thus write your copy semantics using the copy and swap idiom:

```
class String {
    char *p;
    int len;
public:
    // Your constructors...
    // Swap function
    friend void swap(String& s1, String& s2) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(s1.p, s2.p);
        swap(s1.len, s2.len);
    }
    String(String const& other) : p(new char[other.len]()), len(other.len) {
        std::copy(other.p, other.p + len, p);
    }

    String& operator=(String other) {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    // And finally, a destructor:
    /* virtual */ ~String() {
        delete [] p;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is a bad implementation!

Comment: `p = nullptr;` in the destructor is pointless: the object is going away, and there is no way to access `p` after the destructor has run.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no dereferencing on line 3: there is only a replacement of an object with an another. The line 3 calls the constructor of String and assign the object to s1. So two different instances of String are being created but the constructor is not ´recalled´ on the first object but assign the created one to s1. The operator = is used as its default behavior which is to find if there is a constructor that matches the type given to the = operator.

On a side note, the dynamic memory is not freed at any point in the code making it a bad code sample.